# How do you use keytool interactively with java from the command line?

Tags: java, bash, interface, interactive

I tried keytool -genkeypair.  I have to press enter then enter the information keytool asks for and press enter again.  I tried taking out the new-line and carriage-return, but that had no effect.  I want to enter the information first and then press enter once.

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Process p;
            ProcessBuilder pb;
            DataOutputStream DOS;
            BufferedReader BR;
            OutputStream os;
            InputStream is;
            Console cons = System.console();
            String s;
            while(!(s=cons.readLine()).equals("exit")){
                try{
                    pb = new ProcessBuilder(s.split("\\s"));
                    pb.inheritIO();
                    p = pb.start();
                    os = p.getOutputStream();
                    is = p.getInputStream();
                    DOS = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
                    BR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    byte b;
                    while(p.isAlive()){
                        char[] c = cons.readLine().toCharArray();
                        for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
                            if(c[i]!='\r'&c[i]!='\n'){
                                DOS.writeChar(c[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("Bad Command"); }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to send the line terminators to the process.

Comment: And as `readLine()` removes line terminators, the code you have to test for them is pointless. Just do `DOS.write(line+"\r\n");`, where `line` is the `String` result of `readLine()`. You should also loop while `readLine()` isn't returning null, not while `p.isAlive()`.